# How to merge two data frames with duplicate rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`. The `df1` has repeated text wrt column `name` but column `hobby` changes. The `df2` also has repeated text in the column `name`. I want to merge both the data frames and keep everything.

```
df1:
name   hobby

mike   cricket 
mike   football
jack   chess
jack   football
jack   vollyball
pieter sleeping
pieter cyclying
```

my `df2` is

```
df2:
name

mike
pieter 
jack  
mike
pieter
```

Now I have to merge `df2` with `df1` on `name` column
So my resultant `df3` should look like this:

```
df3:
name   hobby

mike   cricket 
mike   football
pieter sleeping
pieter cyclying
jack   chess
jack   football
jack   vollyball
mike   cricket 
mike   football
pieter sleeping
pieter cyclying
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assign an order for `df2`, merge on `name`, then sort by the said order:

```
(df2.assign(rank=np.arange(len(df2)))
    .merge(df1, on='name')
    .sort_values('rank')
    .drop('rank', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
      name      hobby
0     mike    cricket
1     mike   football
4   pieter   sleeping
5   pieter   cyclying
8     jack      chess
9     jack   football
10    jack  vollyball
2     mike    cricket
3     mike   football
6   pieter   sleeping
7   pieter   cyclying
```